# How do I read from a file and store the content in a dynamic 2d array and display it in a grid format?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, 2d

I have a file (input2.txt) that looks like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GgXQ.jpg)

And I want to open that file and store it in a 2d dynamic array. This is in the function main creating the dynamic array (dont ask why its dynamic even though its defined, idk why):(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht74m.jpg)

Here is opening the file, processing it, and (trying) to put the content into the array:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQovH.jpg)

And the second part of my question is how would I display that array to the user? This is what I have for that function:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsvRO.jpg)

These are the library's that I have:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNZvC.jpg)

And finally, this is the output I currently get:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s35zd.jpg)

Please ask me if you need any clarification about anything. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your problem but vector can do the dynamic work for you.

here is the code i thought you asked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
freopen ("input.txt","r",stdin);
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vect;

int n,m;
std::cin>>n>>m;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    std::vector<int> v;
    int t;
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        std::cin>>t;
        v.push_back(t);
    }
    vect.push_back(v);
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){

        std::cout<<vect[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

please tell me if this worked or not.

Comment: Way better now. Though simply opening a `std::ifstream` instead of `freopen()` would be a better solution probably.